# Breakline in java

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, testng, line-breaks

I have to print below line in testNG window. I need a break line on 1st row and below text should print on second row.

```
System.out.println("Actual : "+actualdropdownvalues.get(i)+" || Expected : "+expecteddropdownvalues.get(i));
```

Output should be like this:

1. //This is first row
2. Actual : || Expected :

Can anyone help on this Issue?

Comment: Did you try using `\n` between content of two line or having two `System.out.println()` each having output of one line

Comment: Hi @Ashishkumar Singh, Yes I have two `System.out.println()` - Need a break line between these two lines.

Comment: You can either combine different lines and provide a break line by using `\n` or you can add one more System.out.println between existing two System.out you have